# What job boards focused on UX professionals have you found candidates through?

Tags: jobs, hiring

**Anyone have a suggestions of Job Boards they have hired UX/IxD candidates through.**

Looking for sites that are focused on UX, so you can weed out generalist sites like Monster and Craigslist (unless you really find all your candidates that way).

Company is Northern California Based so and local organizations, like BayChi, would be great suggestions as well as national sites like IXDA.

**On a seperate note, has anyone had success with the IXDA/Coroflot job board?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak of personal experience but I did construct a list for you of UX centric job boards that I think look promising.

[Boxes and Arrows](http://jobs.boxesandarrows.com/jobs) (Also a great site for UX resources)

[UX Design Jobs](http://uxdesignjobs.net/) (also branches out and keeps tabs on UX job listing on many other sites)

[UX Jobs Board](http://www.uxjobsboard.com/)

[IXDA](http://ixda.coroflot.com/public/jobs_browse.asp) (as you mentioned. I think its a good place to find someone)

[Good Experience](http://goodexperience.com/jobs/)

[Just UX Jobs](http://www.justuxjobs.com/)

[UXswitch](http://www.uxswitch.com/) (UX jobs and career advice)